# Why users credentials are not working in my login unit testing?

Tags: laravel, authentication, testing, jwt, phpunit

I'm using PHPUnit for testing my Laravel project.

```
?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use App\Models\User;
use Tests\TestCase;

class LoginTest extends TestCase
{
    public function test_user_can_login():
    {
        $user = User::factory()->create();

        $response = $this->postJson('/api/auth/login', [
            'email'    => $user->email,
            'password' => $user->password,
        ]);

        $response
            ->assertStatus(200)
            ->assertHeader('Authorization')
            ->assertJson([
                'success' => 'Usuário logado com sucesso!',
            ]);
    }
}
```

I want to create a new user for login test flow, but it returns a 400 status response.

> Tests\Feature\LoginTest > user can login
> Expected status code 200 but received 400.
> Failed asserting that 200 is identical to 400.

I have no idea what is going wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: Code 400 means bad requests. Check your request is valid.

Comment: When you get any error in a test, like this one, and you have no idea what is happening, you have to write `$this->whithoutExceptionHandling()` at the beginning of your test.